# Realloc used in a loop

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, realloc

I am trying to simulate the behaviour of vector container when push_back is used. I have created an array of pointers. Each element can have different length, so I need to reallocate every time a new element is stored:

```
   void *reallocf(void *p, size_t s)
{
    void *tmp = realloc(p, s);
    if(tmp) return tmp;
    free(p);
    return NULL;
}
int main(){
   int rows = 9000;
   int cols = 23000; 
   int *matrix = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*rows*cols);

   //counter of elements
   int *nums = new int [rows];
   memset(num, 0, sizeof(int)*rows)

    /* populate matrix*/
            ....
   int **Xcc = new int *[rows];


  for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
      for(k = 0; k < cols; k++){
          if(matrix[i*cols +k] == 0){
             Xcc[i] = (int*) reallocf(Xcc[i], sizeof(int)*(num[i]+1));
             Xcc[i][num[i]] = k;
             num[i]++;
          }
       }
   }
```

}

Basically what I am doing is storing the position of an element that is 0. So, the array `Xcc[i]` is increase by one element every time is needed. The new length will be previous one plus 1, which is going to be stored.

Apparently seems to be fine to me, however it depends on something that I am getting `segmentation faults` and after looking at it from many different angles I am currently stuck. Any help would great, ideas or suggestions.

Comment: You can't use `realloc` with pointers allocated by `new`.

Comment: Well, let's modify that. I am sure it's not the problem, I've been trying with both.

Comment: This doesn't _look_ like C++ code...

Comment: It is c++ code indeed, but there is not realloc in C++

Comment: Also, you say you are getting segfaults? Then have you run the program in a debugger? It will show _where_ you get the segfault, as well as let you examine variables to help you see what might have caused it. However, in this case I should probably add my earlier comment as an answer because it's most likely the culprit.

Comment: A little unrelated note on the terminology... What you are doing is not recursion. Recursion is when a function calls itself, you are simply calling a function in a loop.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sure, you are right. Just a language problem. I meant, called within a loop.

Comment: There's a subtle possibility of a memory leak here: if `realloc` fails, it returns `NULL`. Storing the result of the call to `realloc` in `Xcc[i]` overwrites the pointer that was there, and there's no way to free the memory that it pointed to. **Always** store the result of `realloc` in a separate pointer, then check whether it's `NULL`, then copy it to the original location.

Comment: @Manolete - Just a note that this is *not at all* the way a C++ vector container works. Not even close!

Comment: @BoPersson I guess internally a vector container needs to call realloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the problem is this: when you do

```
int **Xcc = new int *[rows];
```

Xcc[i], for a generic i, is not initialized, then a call to realloc() may sometime work (if Xcc[i] is null) and sometime may not (segfault).

You are missing a:

```
memset(Xcc, 0, sizeof(int*) * rows);
```

Comment: jack, even better: `int **Xcc = new int *[rows]();`

Comment: awesome! Thanks @Jack. Many negative marks for my question, but only one correct answer. I hope some people can take advantage of this question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to explicitly `free` the reallocated pointer by `realloc`. `realloc` frees the pointer passed to it (if its not `NULL`).

So remove `free(p);` from your `reallocf()` function.

And as @ Joachim Pileborg pointed out, you can't reallocate memory allocated with `new`. So change `new` to `malloc`.

Comment: @ Rohan  Thanks, there must be something else as still is very random

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(matrix[i*cols +k] == 0){
         Xcc[i] = (int*) reallocf(Xcc[i], sizeof(int)*(num[i]+1));
         Xcc[i][num[i]] = k; // bad access here
```

First, you are reallocating a memory based on a condition that can be valid for several values of `k` or `j`.
Second, when a realloc fail, you return `null` and try to access to the memory `0` by doing

```
  Xcc[i][num[i]] = k;
```

**Questions**

- What is the role of matrix?
- Why don't you modify `matrix` after `matrix[i*cols +k] == 0` is true?

**Remarks**

- Don't increase by `1`when there is no space! IT is terribly inefficient because after some point, each insertion will requires one realloc.

You don't need `reallocf`. When realloc fails the original memory stay untouched.
If it is not possible to allocate more space for new items, stop the insertion method and return an error.

Comment: @ UmNyobe So, what shall I do? Why does it fail? In case of fail, what shall I do, try it again?